# Providing correct access to git repository

Tags: git

I have followed [the instructions](http://www.instructables.com/id/GitPi-A-Private-Git-Server-on-Raspberry-Pi/?ALLSTEPS) to set up a private git respository on my raspeberry pi.  All goes well until I try

```
git push pi master
```

at that point I get the following error:

```
fatal: Unable to create temporary file '/mnt/data/git-repos/sublime.git/./objects/pack/tmp_pack_XXXXXX': Permission denied
```

My system details are

Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 7.8 (wheezy)
Release:    7.8
Codename:   wheezy

I am logging in to git with the same account `pi` that I used to set up the respository directory on the raspberry pi.  On the raspberry pi I needed to use sudo to set up the directory. How do I give access to my git login to access the directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pretty basic unix permission error.  If you had to use `sudo` to create the folder, that folder is then owned by the root user account.  To change that, you need to use the `chown` (change ownership) command.

Try:
`sudo chown pi:pi -R /path/to/folder_here`

The command above will change the ownership (both user and group) to your user.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, and Jacobm001's answer didn't work for me, so I thought I'd add my solution in case it helps anyone else. Its a partial solution as I am still unable to remotely create a git repo, but I can clone an existing repo from github and then use git to push/pull changes to this repo.

I followed these [instructions](https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/getting-started-with-git) to set up Git on my Pi. However, I encountered an error when trying to remotely add my repo.

```
$ git remote add origin git@github.com/twesleyb/myRepo.git
$ git push -u origin master

ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

The solution, as suggested [here](https://gist.github.com/adamjohnson/5682757), was to insure that my Pi's [SSH](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ssh/passwordless.md) key was set up properly:

```
$ ls ~/.ssh
$ ssh-keygen
# Copy the entire key generated with:
$ cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Paste your entire SSH key into GitHub > Account > Settings > SSH and GPG Keys.
Create a new repository on GitHub, and then clone this in your pi.

```
git clone git@github.com:twesleyb/myRepo.git
```

Hopefully you can now work with this repo on your pi!